# Pandas : Mapping one column values using other dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as described above

I would like to create in the second table an additional feature (Col_to_create) related to the value of feature A.

Table 2 has more than 800 000 samples so that I ask for a faster way to do that.

First table:

```
a      b    
1     100
2     400
3     500
```

Second table:

```
id   Refer_to_A     Col_to_create
0        3               500
1        1               100
2        3               500
3        2               400
4        1               100
```

Comment: Are you supposed to optimize a join

Comment: I didn t understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is you can apply the function on new column of the dataset :

If your dataset is :

```
dataframe_a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [100,400,500]})
dataframe_b = pd.DataFrame({'Refer_to_A': [3,1,3,2,1]})
```

You can try something like :

```
dataframe_b['Col_to_create'] = dataframe_b['Refer_to_A'].apply(lambda col: dataframe_a['b'][col-1])
```

output:

```
   Refer_to_A  Col_to_create
0           3            500
1           1            100
2           3            500
3           2            400
4           1            100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#//apple_ref/Method/pandas.Series.map):

```
df2['Col_to_create'] = df2['Refer_to_A'].map(df1.set_index('a')['b'])
```

Output:

```
    Refer_to_A  Col_to_create
id                           
0            3            500
1            1            100
2            3            500
3            2            400
4            1            100
```